# Can someone elaborate on the subject of "Discursive Hybridity" in Don Quixote?

Tags: spanish-language, don-quixote, miguel-de-cervantes

Our teacher has asked us about the subject of "Discursive Hybridity" in Don Quixote, I've read about it but I'm not still so sure what it actually designates.

So here I am asking for your help. What is "Discursive Hybridity" and how does it appear in *Don Quixote*?

Comment: “The Utopian Nexus in Don Quixote” by Jehenson and Dunn (you can find it in google books) devotes a whole chapter to discursive hybridity in the said novel.